# '-setValue:forKey:' exception when updating the fields of an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have two NSMutableDictionary objects called "dict" and newdict. Then try to assign newdict to the "myfield1" field. However, I'm facing an error.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = @{ @"myfield1" : @{  @"subfield1" : @"mysubfield1" ,
                                           @"subfield2" : @"mysubfield2" },
                              @"myfield2": @"myfield2",
                              @"myfield3": @"myfield3"};
NSMutableDictionary *newdict =  @{  @"subfield1" : @"mynewsubfield1" ,
                                    @"subfield2" : @"mynewsubfield2" };

[dict setValue:newdict forKey:@"myfield1"];
```

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x17db3bb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loc.'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use setObject:forKey

Comment: Yep, simply declaring a dictionary to be mutable (via the pointer) does not make it so.  Dictionaries created with the `@{...}` notation are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "mutableCopy" to make your dictionary of type NSMutableDictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{ @"myfield1" : @{  @"subfield1" : @"mysubfield1" ,
                                                     @"subfield2" : @"mysubfield2" },
                                   @"myfield2": @"myfield2",
                                   @"myfield3": @"myfield3"} mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary *newdict =  [@{  @"subfield1" : @"mynewsubfield1" ,
                                        @"subfield2" : @"mynewsubfield2" } mutableCopy];


dict[@"myfield1"]=newdict;
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `setValue:forKey:` as this is a KVC method, not a dictionary method. Use `setObject:forKey:`. Technically the KVC method will work, but you should generally only use it when you have a specific need to.

Your real problem is that your dictionary instances aren't mutable. Use `mutableCopy` to create mutable versions from your literal definitions. Literal definitions are always immutable.

Comment: Disagree on your first point. `setValue:forKey` has a specific, documented implementation for mutable dictionaries, where if you pass in a nil object, it will remove it, unlike setObject, which will crash.

Comment: @jrturton good point, I've made some revisions to try to be more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Wain, your dictionary instances aren't mutable.

What may be confusing to you is that you declare the variables as `NSMutableDictionary` so you think they will be mutable. But **the `@{ … }` literal syntax** is equivalent to `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:`, thus **creating a (non-mutable) `NSDictionary` instance**.

**The fact that you affect this value to a variable of type `NSMutableDictionary` does not change this and does not make this dictionary magically mutable.**

That's why @Wain correctly suggested to use `mutableCopy` to make this `NSDictionary` an `NSMutableDictionary` so you can call `setValue:forKey:` or `setObject:forKey:` on it. Another way would be to use `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{ … }];` to create your mutable dictionary.

---

In fact, if the `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` warning is ON, which should be the case by default, **you should have a warning like `warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSDictionary *'`** which should have led you to the cause of your problem and its solution. (Always read the warnings, that's not because they are only warnings and they don't make the compilation fail that they are not important!)